# Why does the console displays typeof as object for an array?

Tags: javascript, html, console

```js
var array = new Array("sfsdf", "sdvgsdfswde");
console.log(typeof array);
```

Comment: because an array is an object with special features. for checking an array use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

Comment: In JavaScript, an Array is an object that's used to construct new Arrays. They usually contain methods to traverse, and/or mutate within them, Thus they show up as an Object when try to do a typeof

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = []
typeof a
 ==> "object"
```

because Array is inherited from an type of object.if you want to check its an `Array` or not then use this method

```
 Array.isArray(a) ==> true
```

Comment: @ need to add more description

Answer (score 0):

Well because in Javascript an Array **IS** an object. Check the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

> The JavaScript Array object is a global object that is used in the
>   construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects
>
> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform
>   traversal and mutation operations. Neither the length of a JavaScript
>   array nor the types of its elements are fixed. Since an array's length
>   can change at any time, and data can be stored at non-contiguous
>   locations in the array, JavaScript arrays are not guaranteed to be
>   dense; this depends on how the programmer chooses to use them. In
>   general, these are convenient characteristics; but if these features
>   are not desirable for your particular use, you might consider using
>   typed arrays.